# Find all the combinations from the given set of numbers that apply to some rules

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics

i'd appreciate your help with the following problem:

I have a list of numbers, and a dictionary:

```
my_list = [400, 200, 100, 50, 25]
my_dict = {400: 8, 200:4, 100: 2, 50: 2, 25: 2}
```

I need to find all the possible combinations that may be built from the numbers from my_list, when they should apply the following rules:

1. The same numbers may be in the combination (`[400, 400, 400]` is a valid combination)
2. The order doesn't matter (`[400, 200, 100]` is same as `[100, 200, 400]` for me)
3. The sum of the numbers in the combination should not exceed 1200
4. the sum of the `my_dict[my_list_item]` should not exceed 24 (for example `[400, 400, 400, 100]` is not valid because `my_dict[400]+my_dict[400]+my_dict[400]+my_dict[100] = 8+8+8+2 = 26`, thus it's not a valid combination)

Any ideas for the python algorithm to solve this one.
Thanks

Comment: How would you do it by hand?

Comment: Also, this part is not quite clear - how long may an output "combination" be?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for doing this recursively using iterators to avoid holding too much in memory.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

def combs (numbers, value_of, max_numbers=1200, max_value=24, min_i=0):
    if len(numbers) <= min_i:
        yield []
    else:
        for comb in combs(numbers, value_of, max_numbers, max_value, min_i+1):
            yield comb
            comb_copy = [n for n in comb] # Copy to avoid sharing bugs.
            numbers_sum = sum(comb)
            values_sum = sum([value_of[i] for i in comb])
            while True:
                comb_copy.append(numbers[min_i])
                numbers_sum += numbers[min_i]
                if max_numbers < numbers_sum:
                    break
                values_sum += value_of[numbers[min_i]]
                if max_value < values_sum:
                    break
                yield comb_copy


my_list = [400, 200, 100, 50, 25]
my_dict = {400: 8, 200:4, 100: 2, 50: 2, 25: 2}

for c in combs(my_list, my_dict):
    print(c)
```

Comment: Great code :) But is using recursion good when it comes to problems like these...? I have a feeling that calculating combination straight ahead will reduce the unnecessary calculations that are caused by all the recursion (i.e. there are many repetition of the same combinations)

Comment: @KentaNomoto If you are asked to calculate a count, recursion like this is horrible because the output can be so large.  But here we are asked to actually find the combinations.  There aren't a lot of good alternatives to recursion - the best you can do is limit how much memory is used in producing a large amount of output.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Yes. Recursion is probably the most efficient approach you can take here. As you said, the memory used from a very large input is significantly lower compared to other methods.

Comment: @KentaNomoto Note that the trick is not just recursion.  It is recursion and iterators.  That way you only have to hold where you are in generating combinations in memory, instead of the whole data structure.  Merely generating the full data set recursively won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the list of "every combinations of your list **with** repetition", I wrote a code that calculates it.

It uses a while loop that increments the combination length counter every time.
Since the length of the combination can grow infinitely, the indicator is used to stop the loop, which activates when not a single combination was find.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

my_list = [400, 200, 100, 50, 25]
my_dict = {400: 8, 200:4, 100: 2, 50: 2, 25: 2}

final_list = []

combinationLength = 1
while True:
    c = list(combinations_with_replacement(my_list, combinationLength)) #generate every combination of length combinationLength
    countNextCombination = False #indicator to break the while loop

    for combination in c: 
        if (sum(combination) <= 1200):
            dicsum=0
            for j in combination:
                dicsum+=my_dict[j]
            if (dicsum<=24):
                final_list.append(list(combination))
                countNextCombination = True

    if countNextCombination == False: #if not a single combination was valid, finish the loop
        break
    combinationLength += 1

print (final_list)
```

Comment: The problem asks "find the combinations" and not "find how many combinations".  You are therefore answering a different question.

Comment: @btilly  What do you mean? The "final_list" variable is the list of all the combinations.

Edit: Oh I see now, the combinationLength variable naming might be a little misleading. It is not the length of the total combination, instead it is the variable to hold the length of the combination (for example [200,100,100] is combinationLength of 3)

Comment: Right you are.  My bad.  In which case the amount of memory that you could wind up holding in memory is so extreme that your code won't run at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using itertools, you won't need a recursive solution.  The combinations_with_replacement iterator will provide the combinations for you and you only need to check your conditions.  For your requirement, you will need a *power set* of the combinations (i.e. combinations of all sizes):

for example:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as combine

my_list = [400, 200, 100, 50, 25]
my_dict = {400: 8, 200:4, 100: 2, 50: 2, 25: 2}

for size in range(2,len(my_list)+1):
    for combo in combine(my_list, size):
        if sum(combo) <= 1200 \
        and sum(my_dict[c] for c in combo) <= 24:
            print(combo)
```

*You can place this in a function and use `yield combo` instead of `print(combo)` if you're going to process the combinations in some way*

output:

```
(400, 400)
(400, 200)
(400, 100)
(400, 50)
(400, 25)
...
(50, 50, 50, 50, 50)
(50, 50, 50, 50, 25)
(50, 50, 50, 25, 25)
(50, 50, 25, 25, 25)
(50, 25, 25, 25, 25)
(25, 25, 25, 25, 25)
```

Note that this is a, non-optimized, brute force approach that may be OK for small data sets but will take an exponential amount of time as you have more data.   There are more advanced methods (using recursion) that will skip whole swats of combinations by checking for  partial sums and/or using meoization.